# Code signing no longer working

Tags: c#, windows, digital-signature, signature, cryptoapi

We have a legacy Windows Workflow process that uses `SignerSign` to apply a digital signature to an EXE. We are migrating away from the Windows Workflow process, and so I have been preparing a tool within the context of our new process to perform the same signing operation. I copy/pasted the code signing code from the Workflow Activity to a class in the new project, but I am encountering an error when I try to run it.

The rough outline of what the code does is:

- `CertOpenStore` is used to open the PFX file containing the private key and certificate.
- A certificate context is obtained by calling `CertEnumCertificatesInStore` on the resulting certificate store handle.
- `SignerSign` is called with a `SIGNER_SUBJECT_INFO` pointing at the target EXE file, a `SIGNER_CERT` pointing at the certificate context from the previous step and a `SIGNATURE_SIGNER_INFO` specifying that the SHA-1 algorithm should be used. (I have tried changing the algorithm to SHA-2 512 with no change in the outcome.) The `pProviderInfo` parameter is `NULL`.
- A separate call is made to `SignerTimeStamp` to apply a timestamp to the signature. A comment in the code indicates that if the `pwszHttpTimeStamp` parameter to `SignerSign` is used, it returns HRESULT 0x80070020 ("File in use"?)

When I try to run this code on Windows 10 64-bit, whether from a 32-bit or 64-bit process, I get error HRESULT 0x80092006 "No provider was specified for the store or object.". I tried supplying a `pProviderInfo` with the provider name set to "Microsoft Strong Cryptographic Provider" (seen in the API Monitor trace output for when SignTool.exe signs the executable -- this works) but it did not affect the outcome.

Does anyone know what exactly this error means and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea at all why this worked, but by massaging my code so that does the same thing I see SignTool doing in Rohitab's API Monitor, and then paring bits away to what appears to be the minimal working set, this now signs files again:

- Instead of `CertOpenStore`,. `PFXImportCertStore` is used to open the PFX file and produce an `HCERTSTORE`. This requires loading the PFX into memory so that it can be passed in as a `CRYPT_DATA_BLOB` -- no big deal.
- A certificate context is obtained using `CertEnumCertificatesInStore` as before.
- `CertGetCertificateChain` is used on the resulting certificate context with an unrestrictive `CERT_CHAIN_PARA` and flags `CERT_CHAIN_DISABLE_PASS1_QUALITY_FILTERING |    CERT_CHAIN_RETURN_LOWER_QUALITY_CONTEXTS | CERT_CHAIN_REVOCATION_CHECK_CHAIN_EXCLUDE_ROOT`. No additional store is specified. When I originally wrote this, based on the API Monitor results, I defined `CERT_CHAIN_PARA_HAS_EXTRA_FIELDS` and populated them the same way the API Monitor capture showed, but I continue to get `S_OK` from `SignerSign` with the short `CERT_CHAIN_PARA` structure as well.
- `SignerSign` is called as before, except that a dummy collection-type store is passed in as the `hCertStore` of the `SIGNER_CERT_STORE_INFO` struct nested within the `SIGNER_CERT`. This dummy collection type store is created by calling `CertOpenStore` twice, once with `CERT_STORE_PROV_COLLECTION` and flag `CERT_STORE_CREATE_NEW_FLAG` and once with `CERT_STORE_PROV_MEMORY` specifying encodings `PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING | X509_ASN_ENCODING`, and then adding the memory store to the collection store using `CertAddStoreToCollection`.

If the dummy collection type store is not specified, then `SignerSign` complains that it cannot find a path to a trusted root. Note that the certificate I am using in my testing is self-signed, and thus doesn't *have* a path to a trusted root. Perhaps the dummy collection type store would not be necessary with a code signing certificate that does have a path to a trusted root, I do not presently have the means to test.

In any case, I hope this helps resolve this issue for anybody else who might have bumped into problems with `SignerSign`. :-)